# The parameters of a CNN model is returning None

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, federated-learning

i create a CNN model like this `global_model = CNNMnist(args=args)`. Then i send it to device, set it to train. Then i train my local models, collect the local_weights and the average them to get updated global_model.
Now i am trying to get the items from the `.parameters()` function but all i get is `None` as `item.grad`. When i do the same thing for the local_models, i get the desired output. What am i doing wrong?

```
global_model.to(device)
global_model.train()
...................
global_weights = average_weights(local_weights)
global_model.load_state_dict(global_weights)
last_update = []
for item in global_model.parameters():
    last_update.append(copy.deepcopy(item.grad))
    print(item.grad)

Output: None None None None None None None None
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at values you loaded from a `state_dict` - the gradients are not saved there. try print `.grad` just after your call to `backward()` and before `zero_grad()`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. that works. but i do have another question, the `backward()` only appears in the local_model updates. the global_model is updated bu averaging the updated weights i got from the local_models. How do i get the gradients of the global_model if i don't use `backward()` in global_model?